# Flexbox issues in Safari 10.0.1

Tags: css, safari, flexbox

I have [some code set up over at jsBin](http://jsbin.com/xaguha/19/edit?html,css,output) to test out flexbox, and it works fine in evey browser I threw at it (including IE11), but in Safari 10.0.1, the `.img` element doesn't get stretched to the height of its parent element. Any ideas?

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      background: #f7f7f7;
    }

    h1 {
      padding-left: 20px;
    }

    .text {
      font-size: 12px;
      font-family: serif;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="article">
        <div class="figure">
          <div class="img">
             <img src="http://json.tv/images/general/2014/09/08/thumbnail-20140908100224-3296.jpg" />
          </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="text">
          <span class="cat">Lifestyle</span>
          <h1>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
          </h1>
          <span class="date">6. 6. 1966</span>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
img {
  position:  absolute;
  height:    100%;
  left:      50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.img {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.figure, .text {
  width:    50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  float:    left;
}

.article {
  display:    flex;
  min-height: 280px;
  max-width:  690px;

  background: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not seeing the issue in safari 9.1.3.

I would use  webkit prefixing for flex.  and it looks like you are just putting display:flex; on everything and assigning no flex value  i'd try something like this for your wrappers.  as far as your image styles i cannot see exactly what you are trying to get.  Setting the height of the image to 100% is an issue because that only works when the parent has a static height.  it looks like, between that and the overflow hidden, you may be trying to achieve something like background-size: cover;. id look into that.

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/centering-elements-with-flexbox/

http://codepen.io/ErwanHesry/pen/JcvCw

```
.wrapper, .article {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.figure, .text {
  -webkit-flex:1;
  flex:1;
}

.article {
  min-height: 280px;
  max-width:  690px;
  background: white;
}
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i've set up flex on the .wrapper element as well because I initially wanted there to be multiple .article elements, all aligned using flex. I'll update the question

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `.img` element altogether did the trick. It's as if Safari stretches only the immediate element relative to the flex container (at least in the case of when there's an absolutely positioned image in play).

[See jsBin](http://jsbin.com/xaguha/18/edit?html,css,output)